# Why static is needed in the one case and is not mandatory in another one?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

FreePascal, Delphi mode. After some experiments I found that this code is compiled, FPC says me that class procedure must be "static". But my question is: then why operator `Equal` does not need "static" and it's compiling fine?! Also I can not understand what is the difference to have "class" procedure and "class" with "static" (for example, in Python in `classmethod` you get argument - reference to the class, in `staticmethod` - you have not such argument).

```pascal
  type TPos = record
    FLine: Word;
    FPos: Word;

    class procedure Init(out a: TPos); static;
    class operator Equal(a, b: TPos): Boolean;
  end;
```

PS. I set "delphi" tag because: 1) it's written in delphi mode 2) because I found the same documentation for Delphi: about class and static keywords.

Comment: It might be related to "Record Management Operators", a kind of RAII like FPC only extension

Comment: It's a design decision made by the compiler engineers / language designers: They could have simply made the static keyword implicit in both cases, but they didn't. It annoys the hell out of me every time I encounter it,because it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what you state, a non-static class method does have a reference to the class passed as an argument. It's an implicit argument named `Self`.

For class methods on records as opposed to classes, since there is no inheritance, this `Self` parameter would serve no purpose, and so it is never passed. Hence all class methods on records must be static.

A class operator is implicitly a static method and so you don't need to state that. In other words, `operator` implies `static`.

Comment: Not only would a `Self` parameter on a record class method serve no purpose, it wouldn't really have any possible (reasonable) value, would it?

Comment: @Andreas True, the current language does not support meta classes for records but in principle it could.